# How to connect to Elasticsearch server remotely using load balancer

Tags: elasticsearch, remote-server

There might be a post which  I am looking for. I have very limited time and got requirement at the last moment. I need to push the code to QA and setup elasticsearch with admin team. Please respond me as soon as possible or share the link which has similar post!!.

I have scenario wherein I will have multiple elasticsearch servers,  one is hosted on USA , another one in UK and one more server is hosted in India within the same network(companies network) which shares same cluster name.  I can set multicast to false and unicast to provide host and IP address information to form a topology. 
   Now in my application I know that I  have to use Transport cLient as follows,

```
Settings settings = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder()
        .put("cluster.name", "myClusterName").build();
Client client = new TransportClient(settings)
        .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress("host1", 9300))
        .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress("host2", 9300));
```

Following are my concerns,

1) As per the above information, admin team will  just provide the single ip address that is load balancer  ip address and the loadbalancer will manage the request and response handling .I mean the loadbalance is responsible  to redirect to the respective elasticsearch server . Here my question is, Is it okay to use Transport client to connect to the host with the portnumber as follows ,

```
new TransportClient(settings)
        .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress("loadbalancer-ip-address", “loadbalance-port-number”)) ;

If loadbalancer will redirect the request to elastcisearch server  what should be the configuration to loadbalancer like, we need to provde all the elasticsearch host or ipaddress details to it?  so that  at any given point of time , if there is any failure to the master elasticsearch server it will pick another  master.
```

2) What is the best configuration for 4 nodes or elasticsearch servers like, shards , replicas and etc. 
Each node will have one  primary shard and 1 replicate ?   which can be configured in elasticsearch.yml
Please  replay me  as soon as possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any response, please.

Comment: @ lakshmikanth Did you get solution for this. We have the same problem and looking for solution.